# How to get to another page after saving form by CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I wan't to get to order_list page after adding new order.

Was trying both reverse and reverse_lazy method also just to set page adres value to success_url directly like success_url = 'orders/order_list' or sucess url = 'order_list' but it always returns me Http 405 error.

views.py

```
django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Order
from .forms import CreateOrder
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



# Create your views here.

class OrderCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):

        login_url = '/login_required'
        permission_required = 'orders.add-order'
        model = Order
        success_url = reverse_lazy('orders:order_list')

        fields = ['airport', 'direction', 'adress', 'client', 'telephone', 'flight_number', 'plane', 'pick_up', 'gate', 'driver']
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


from orders.views import OrderCreateView, OrderListView, AboutView, LoginRequiredView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('add_order/', OrderCreateView.as_view(template_name="orders/add_order.html"), name="add_order"),
    path('order_list/', OrderListView.as_view(), name="order_list"),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="pages/login.html"), name="login"),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="pages/logout.html"), name="logout"),
    path('about/', AboutView.as_view(), name="about"),
    path('login_required/', LoginRequiredView.as_view(), name='login_required')

]
```

add_order.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="container" style="width: 40%; height: 80%;">


            <div class="page header">
                <h1>Add new order</h1>
            </div>
            <form action="/order_list/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save order</button>
            </form>
        </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('orders:order_list')
```

To:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('order_list')
```

---

And change:

```
<form action="/order_list/" method="post">
```

To:

```
<form action="/add_order/" method="post">
```

**Note**: You are using hardcoded URL which is not recommended. Use the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag.

Comment: Was trying it too. Still 405

Comment: [06/Oct/2019 05:48:37] "GET /add_order/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6367
Method Not Allowed (POST): /order_list/
Method Not Allowed: /order_list/
[06/Oct/2019 05:49:03] "POST /order_list/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check!

Comment: I dont know if it's right to thanks in comments but i can't vote your post yet. It's working anyway, thank you